# Are non-template friends of template classes instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend, friend-function

Consider the following code :

```
//Allows to automatically define post in/de-crement operators from their pre- version
template<typename T>
struct Arithmetic
{
    //Not a template?
    friend constexpr auto operator++(T& l, int)
    { auto old = l; ++l; return old; }


    friend constexpr auto operator--(T& l, int)
    { auto old = l; --l; return old; }
};

//Only defines increment
struct Foo : Arithmetic<Foo>
{
    int val;
    Foo& operator++() { ++val; return *this; }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo f;
    f.val = 12;
    ++f;
    f++;

    return 0;
}
```

If I tried to define the post-decrement operator "manually" (outside of `Arithmetic`), I would get an error on `--l;` because the pre-decrement operator is not defined. As non-template friends of template classes are apparently not considered template functions, I would expect the same behaviour.

But as it is, the code compiles just fine for C++17 (at least on msvc and gcc). Why is that so? Is this kind of function a specific case of non-template function that still gets instanciated?

What parts of the standard allow or prevent me from doing such things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-template friend function defined in a template class is a templated entity.

From the C++ 20 Standard (13.1 Preamble)

> 8 A templated entity is
>
> (8.1) — a template,
>
> (8.2) — an entity defined (6.2) or created (6.7.7) in a templated
>   entity,
>
> (8.3) — a member of a templated entity,
>
> (8.4) — an enumerator for an enumeration that is a templated entity,
>   or
>
> (8.5) — the closure type of a lambda-expression (7.5.5.1) appearing in
>   the declaration of a templated entity
>
> [Note: A local class, a local variable, **or a friend function defined
>   in a templated entity is a templated entity**. —end note]

It is instantiated when it is required. So in this class definition

```
//Only defines increment
struct Foo : Arithmetic<Foo>
{
    int val;
    Foo& operator++() { ++val; return *this; }
};
```

the templated entity

```
friend constexpr auto operator--(T& l, int)
{ auto old = l; --l; return old; }
```

is not instantiated.

In the case when the friend function only declared in the template class `struct Arithmetic` and is defined outside the class for its specialization then the compiler will issue an error because the operator `--l` is not declared in the `class Foo`.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I am looking for! Do you have any reference that explains the specificities of templated entities?

Comment: @AlexandreS. I found one definition.:) See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

> If I tried to define the post-decrement operator "manually" (outside of Arithmetic), I would get an error on `--l`;

Those are indeed not template functions, so you have to provide manually the function for each `T`, here version for `Foo`:

```
constexpr auto operator--(Foo& l, int)
{
    auto old = l; --l; return old;
}
```

Comment: The posted code compiles correctly as it is though, no need for additional definitions https://godbolt.org/z/Ko5NXH

Comment: @Jarod42 You are wrong. The friend functions are already defined within each specialization of the template class Arithmetic including the specialization Arithmetic<Foo>

Comment: @jdehesa: If OP tried to define manually outside of arithmetic, I suppose OP also remove then the "inline" definition. (Sad that OP posted working version and not the problematic's one).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I understand that OP wants to move definition to outside of the template class...

Comment: @Jarod42 Just to clarify : My goal is not to move the definitions outside of `Arithmetic`, I'm trying to understand why that function compiles while inside `Arithmetic` but not when outside.

Comment: Compile from outside... [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/481e580bd9d52044).